# POST request with Axios not sending data to my server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, docker, axios

Here is my **React** code for the form submission:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('item:', item);
    Axios.post('http://<MY_SERVER>/item/add', {name:item})
      .then(response => console.log(response))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };
```

and this is the code in my **Node API**:

```
// Add a new Item
app.post('/item/add', (req, res) => {
  const newItem = new Item({
    name: req.body.name
  });

  newItem.save()
    .then(item => {
    res.json({msg: 'success'});
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

When I run the handleSubmit nothing happens. I only get the console.logs... Also, here is the error from my server

```
'ValidationError: item validation failed: name: Path' `name` is required
```

So it is clear that the data sent over to the api is never received. I've tried changing it up in many ways I have came across online but no luck.

Comment: Are you using bodyparser at node side ?

Comment: @AmolBJamkar yes

Comment: Are you sure item variable has a value in the front-end?

Comment: Did you find req.body in console.log? and are you sure the node/express function working when you hit post request?

Comment: Pls make everything clear.
- You can check if your backend is going well with Postman.
- If backend is okay, then check your frontend with Chrome's Inspect-> Network.

Comment: I checked the network tab and it says the request is pending. I also tested the endpoint with Postman and it was successful

Answer (score 1):

I have attached both ways to post data i.e. Form URL Encoded and JSON. For sending Form Url Encoded data we need an additional Library `querystring`.

You can install it using `npm install query-string`

Here is the code for both the requests. You don't need `query-string` if you are using content type application/json.

Here you go

```
var axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('querystring');

function sendFormUrlEncodedData() {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  };

  const payload = {
    name: 'morpheus',
    job: 'leader'
  };

  //Send data with form url using querystring node package for it.
  axios
    .post('https://reqres.in/api/users', qs.stringify(payload), {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

function sendJSONData() {
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  };

  const payload = {
    name: 'morpheus',
    job: 'leader'
  };

  //Send data with JSON, so stringifying it.
  axios
    .post('https://reqres.in/api/users', JSON.stringify(payload), {
      headers: headers
    })
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

sendFormUrlEncodedData();
sendJSONData();
```

Answer (score -1):

First  of all check whether your backend code is working or not by using postman. I think you are getting validation error because of the error of your backend code. And also check whether that you are implemented the name attribute correctly with its data type.
After that update, the react code as below.

```
import axios from 'axios';


constructor() {
  this.item = {
    name: ''
  }
}

 handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('item:', this.item.name);
    event.preventDefault();

    axios.post('http://<MY_SERVER>/item/add', this.item)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

}
```

Comment: Backend is working correctly. I tested the endpoint numerous times. However, the data is not being sent with the Axios.post request

Comment: Can you check your react code with my code which I mentioned in the above?